Horizonal Ribbons on Resin prints
What causes these horizonal ribbons on my prints.
My Printer is an Anycubic Photon Mono X 6K.
Clear 01

Clear 02

Grey

I have searched and tried everything that I can find
but nothing works.
I've tried different color resins,
I've tried to arrange my models differently on the build
plate,
I've tried different slicers, Lychee and ChituBox.
I've heated my shop to 90 degrees, I've heated
my resin, and I've asked around, but nobody seems
to know the answer.
It's very annoying because it causes a lot of clean up.
Can anybody help me?

Any time you get "excess printing," look for excess illumination. One can usually expect no light leaking into the vat from the outside, which means it has to be coming into the vat from the LCD panel.
One method of troubleshooting is to empty the vat, even remove the build plate and send the job to the printer. You'll want to cover the LCD with a sheet of paper to protect your vision from the UV light but allow the illumination to be visible.
Consider any one of the failed jobs and how far into the print that the ribbons appear. Examine the "print" as it appears on the paper to see if you're getting extraneous data manifesting itself as printed material.
Some slicers (Prusa is one of them, not sure of others) will slice each layer and store it in the print file as a PNG image, then zip them together for the firmware to "peel off" for printing. I'm not sure about Lychee and Chitubox, however. The individual PNG images can also be examined for ribbons and undesired print regions.
The paper sheet method is the least wasteful and probably the most time consuming, but likely to be illuminating, pun intended.

I suggest to check the print file first because the ribbons might be part of the commands sent to the printer. Lychee and Chitu also do the same as prusa, just a different wrapper
